# Can you use feats in the warblade maneuver emerald razor?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, tome-of-battle

The diamond mind path maneuver EMERALD RAZOR states:

> As part of this maneuver, make a single melee attack against an
>   opponent. This is a touch attack rather than a standard melee attack.
>   If you hit, you deal normal melee damage.

Does it mean you can use any feat that enhances a standard melee attack like Power attack or weapon focus?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## Yes, so long as it does not require its own action

Using *emerald razor* is a standard action; you cannot apply its benefit to any other type of action, or to another standard action. So no *emerald razor* on a charge or whatever.

But it is still a weapon attack, and everything that would benefit just any weapon attack applies to it. That includes both Power Attack and Weapon Focus. The attack you make with *emerald razor* is exactly like any other attack you would have made, except it target’s touch AC instead of regular AC. Everything else is the same.

For the record, it’s far from the only way to achieve this. The core *brilliant energy* weapon property does this for **all** your attacks, though it does have a large drawback in its inability to attack constructs or undead. The *wraithstrike* spell from *Spell Compendium* allows the caster to target touch AC with all attacks for one round, as a swift action. The Deep Impact feat from *Expanded Psionics Handbook* allows you to treat any attack (including that as part of a charge, full-attack, or some other maneuver) as a touch attack if you expend Psionic Focus.

Comment: There's also [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36231/8610), information from which might also apply since the querent didn't specify which feats nor what *enhances* means.